# How do I enable "View All" access to an Organic Group Content Type?

Tags: organic-groups, users

I have a Setup such as following:

```
- Organic Group - Institution
- Organic Group Content - Query
```

I want the following:
1. Allow group members to only view the Queries created by themselves (i.e. View Own).
2. Allow the group administrators to View all Queries in their group.

How do I achieve this?

I tried using the `Content Access` Module and gave the Query Content Type "View Own Permission", this solves the first problem but doesn't allow the group administrators to View all Queries.